# How to use a parameter to select one or more columns in a SELECT statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a function that is able to select particular columns from a SQLite 3 table. The idea is to do something like this:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("my_db.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
def my_func(parameter_list):
    con.execute("SELECT parameter_list FROM a_table")
    return cursor.fetchall()
```

where the `parameter_list` contains the names of the columns the user wants selected.

I've tried using `?` placeholders, but:

1. I still need to use a fixed amount in the `SELECT` statement itself;
2. for some reason the output is the names of the columns, not the contents. What I want to do is let the user determine the number of columns and which columns exactly he'd like to fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get a comma-separated string for the columns, right? can be done like his:

```
"SELECT {} FROM a_table".format(','.join(parameter_list))
```

Comment: So, the method suggested by Sergey works - I can edit my SQL command string the way I want. However, I've read somewhere else that using .format() isn't such a good practice, that I should strive to use parameters. Besides, I'm concerned about SQL injection vulnerabilities. 
So, given the fact that I plan on building the SQL statements inside functions, and replacing parts of the command string via .format(), will my code still be vulnerable to SQL injection?